# Logically how to detect headline, content and background color from a given array of colors?

Tags: php, image, colors, uicolor, color-scheme

I was wondering if anyone can help me as to how to get a headline, content and background color, from a given array of colors?

for example Having the following [color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS69J.png), It's obvious that the first color on the left is going to be for the headline, the second as a background and the forth for the content, I've been searching all over for this with no luck part of that is not knowing what search for exactly, my question is what sort of rules or how to process that color palette to come up with these assumption pragmatically?

Note: I'm using a php library to convert colors between RGB <> HSL <> HEX.

Comment: Your question is not clear. In what format are you getting the colour palette? Is the order the same for each palette, or are you using some rules to determine which colour is for what?

Comment: I'm getting my color palette in RGB format, it's not the same for every process as it's generated from an image provided by the user.

Comment: I mean in PHP, is it an array?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes, it's generated in an array

Comment: Also, how do you determine which color is for what, do you have an algorithm or is it just in the order they're given?

Comment: That's exactly what i need to figure out, an algorithm to get for example the first color as the headline but respectively on different palettes since their order is different each time.

Comment: So the real question is, how do you decide which colour is for the headline? Is it the brightest? the one with the most green?. You need to determine this for the headline, content and background before you can ask a computer to do it for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, Visually you just get that by looking at them, what sort of rules should I follow to get to the same result pragmatically?

Comment: I'm not any good at design, and I'm certainly not an expert on colouration. You need to look any many different samples and work out what makes one colour stand out as being suitable for a specific role across all of those samples, be it intensity or some other factor (possibly a mix of two or more). Then you need to work out how a program can get that value.

Comment: Thank you  Roshan, I was just hoping if anyone can give me a push in the right direction, for example what should I be looking for ?